# How to Prevent Ad networks from redirecting users in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, security

In the world of digital advertising, almost all the big players give publishers a java script tag. Unfortunately most of them benefit from that to serve a pop, pop under or open new tabs.

For our case we don't want to prevent the user from closing and using the native browser actions but as all our links only redirect to our unique domain pages, we don't want any page to be opened.

We tried many thing with the `before unload` java script event but we cannot cover all the use cases.

I would like to thank you in advance if you have any approach to prevent any redirection to a URL that is different from our domain except native browser interactions.

scripts are loaded this way in the HTML header or in inside any div elements:
`<script data-cfasync="false" async type="text/javascript" src="//big-ad-network-different-from-google"></script>`

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove event listeners after page load?
If you will do so, ad JavaScript will newer receive an event, and don't open the new page!

Comment: Yes we tried to unbind all the click events but it's useless